# destruction order of promise and return object for C++ coroutine

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <coroutine>

class eager {
public:
    struct promise_type {
        promise_type() { std::cout << "promise_type ctor" << std::endl; }
        ~promise_type() { std::cout << "~promise_type dtor" << std::endl; }
        struct return_object {
            return_object() { std::cout << "return_object ctor" << std::endl; }
            ~return_object() { std::cout << "~return_object dtor" << std::endl; }
            operator eager() { return {}; }
        };
        auto get_return_object() noexcept { return return_object{}; }
        constexpr auto initial_suspend() const noexcept { return std::suspend_never{}; }
        constexpr auto final_suspend() const noexcept { return std::suspend_never{}; }
        constexpr auto return_void() const noexcept {}
        auto unhandled_exception() -> void { throw; }
    };
};

auto coroutine() -> eager {
    co_return;
}

auto main() -> int
{
    coroutine();
    return 0;
}
```

You can see the result for MSVC, clang and GCC here: https://godbolt.org/z/Yan9s9TPE

According to lots of articles about coroutine, the `coroutine()` will be transformed into...

```cpp
auto coroutine() -> eager {
    eager::promise_type promise;
    auto res = promise.get_return_object();
    // initial suspend
    promise.return_void();
    // final suspend
    return res;
}
```

At a glance, since the promise object is constructed first, I thought it would be the last object to be destructed.

However, MSVC and GCC show reverse order:

```
// from MSVC/GCC
promise_type ctor
return_object ctor
~promise_type dtor
~return_object dtor
```

On the other hand, clang shows what I expected:

```
// from clang
promise_type ctor
return_object ctor
~return_object dtor
~promise_type dtor
```

Which one is right?
Or, is the destruction order of promise object and return object just unspecified by standard?

Comment: What happens if you implement either [the rule of three or the rule or five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) with debugging output for copying (and perhaps moving) as well?

Comment: Also, what versions of MSVC and Clang are you using? If they use different C++ standard versions then behavior might indeed differ.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude As far as I know about coroutine, there's no chance to occur copy or move here because both of promise and return object will be created once and never go out the scope here. You can see the compiler informations in the godbolt link. I'll update the link to include the latest gcc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> According to lots of articles about coroutine

Then "lots of articles about coroutine[sic]" are incorrect.

The result object is not on the coroutine stack. It *cannot be* on the coroutine stack, because it's the *result object* for the initial call to the coroutine.

All that [the C++ standard says about `get_result_object` is this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.fct.def.coroutine#7):

> The expression `promise.get_­return_­object()` is used to initialize the glvalue result or prvalue result object of a call to a coroutine.
> The call to get_­return_­object is sequenced before the call to `initial_­suspend` and is invoked at most once.

It happens before `initial_suspend` and it gets called once. That's all it has to say. Therefore, everything else about result objects from functions work as normal; in this case, it simply gets initialized before the function properly starts instead of when the function is about to return.

By C++'s normal rules, a function's result object is on the caller's stack, not the stack of the function being called. So when `promise.get_result_object()` is evaluated, it is initializing storage provided by the caller.

`main` discards the result of the expression `coroutine()`. This means that it will manifest a temporary from the prvalue result object, and the type of this temporary will be `eager`. The temporary will be destroyed, but only *after* control returns to `main`.

Here's the tricky part: the return prvalue from `get_result_object()` is *not* `eager`. It's `eager::promise::result_object`. Initializing the return value requires performing an implicit conversion from `result_object` to `eager`. This requires manifesting a temporary of type `result_object` to perform that conversion on.

The [standard rule for destroying temporaries is](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.temporary#4.sentence-3):

> Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression ([intro.execution]) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.

But... what is the "full-expression" here?

One would assume it would be the `promise.get_result_object()` expression. But is that a "full-expression" by C++'s rules? These rules are [rather esoteric and technical](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.execution#5). One could argue that `promise.get_result_object()` is being used to initialize an object and therefore it is de-facto an "init-declarator". But "init-declarator" is a piece of grammar, and `promise.get_result_object()` is not stated by the text to be an "init-declarator".

An argument could be made that the only expression that is *certainly* a full expression is `coroutine()`. And therefore, one could make the argument that any temporaries used to initialize the return value object should persist until control returns to the caller.

I would argue that the standard wording is under-specified and therefore both versions are equally legitimate until clarification is provided. Clang's version makes more sense (but not for the reasons you claim), but the others are at least arguable.

Comment: @user17732522: I updated the post to reflect the issue. I argue that the temporary lifetime is ambiguous, due to the "full-expression" notation and that the standard doesn't really say that the initialization of the return value object is, itself, a "full-expression".

Comment: I guess one could argue that https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.execution#5.6 applies, since there is no enclosing expression, although "_otherwise part of a full-expression_" is not clear to me either.

Comment: But then I guess "_Conversions applied to the result of an expression in order to satisfy the requirements of the language construct in which the expression appears are also considered to be part of the full-expression._" or "_For an initializer, performing the initialization of the entity [...] is also considered part of the full-expression_" might apply, in which case maybe it would be GCC/MSVC that are correct. Yeah, seems unclear.